# ComboBox with multiple clickable columns

Tags: c#, wpf, combobox

I'm trying to create a dropdown menu where you can select hours, minutes, and seconds. I manage to create one combo box at a time and bind it to an array. But is there a way to combine hours, minutes and seconds into a single ComboBox? Unfortunately, I couldn't find anything on the internet, or it didn't work for me.

I'm new to C# and WPF, so I'm probably doing something wrong.

Many thanks for your help!

Comment: Could you use a [`TimePicker`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/uwp/api/windows.ui.xaml.controls.timepicker?view=winrt-22621) control for this? (Never used it myself, so I don't really know if it's suitable...)

Comment: There are a few Date*Time Edit controls in the Web that you'd probably find via Web  Search, see also https://www.codeproject.com/search.aspx?q=wpf+datetimepicker. My personal favorite so far is the Syncfusion version, a commercial product, but they are also offering a "community" license: https://help.syncfusion.com/wpf/datetimepicker/getting-started